# Recursively copying a directory using native C code

Tags: c, linux

I was looking to implement the behavior of Linux command `cp -Rf <src_dir>/* <dst_dir>` that copies everything inside the 'src_dir' into 'dst_dir' recursively

I looked online for help and got a few solutions but they did either of the following that I do not want to do:

1. using `rename(src_dir, dst_dir)`, which essentially 'moves' the contents and not copies.
   I need to keep the contents of the 'src_dir' intact.
2. Opening to read each file int the 'src_dir'.
   I would like to do this w/o opening the files and reading the content.

Can the above be achieved with C without using `system("cp -Rf <src_dir>/* <dst_dir>")`?

(Edited the original question after realising from a few initial comments that the original lang was confusing)

Comment: IMO no. You need at least `opendir` and `readdir`, otherwise how could you read the directory? For reading/writing the files you can use standard `fopen`/`fread` C functions, but even they end up calling `read`/`write` etc. So what are you _actually_  trying to achieve? Do you want to write a platform independent program?

Comment: If you wish to do I/O operation, you have to use system calls or a function built upon system calls.

Comment: Your requirement/s are still unrealistic.  Clarify/fix them.  Some OS may offer calls like 'CopyFile()', but that ties you to a specific API.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: the question is tagged `linux` so I guess that `codify` wants a Linux specific answer.

Comment: 'I looked online for help and got a few solutions but they did either of the following that I do not want to do' well, that should have been your first clue that what you want is not available.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch OK:)  Is there anything in the linux API's that umm.. copies files without explicitly reading and writing them, (don't ask me - it's OP's requirement:)?

Comment: Now that you have edited the question the answer has changed from **NO** to **YES**. BTW the `cp` command is written in C.

Answer (score 2):

> I was looking to implement the behavior of linux system commands
>
> 1) cp   that copies everything inside the 'src_dir' into 'dst_dir' recursively,

---

> Can the above be achieved using C (and no linux system calls)?

Of course not; remember that a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) is the main way an application can interact with the Linux kernel: look on [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) for an exhaustive list of system calls (you are likely to need [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)...). Do not confuse system calls with calls to the C library [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) function (which uses [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) etc....)

However, you might be interested in [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) (which of course is implemented above several system calls). Look also into [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) & [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)

You cannot change anything on the file systems without going thru system calls.

#### addenda

(the question has changed to)

> Can the above be achieved with C without using system("cp -Rf /* ")?

Yes; you could use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) first to scan the file tree (or play appropriately with [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) etc...), then detect the directories to be made (using [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html)...); you'll make appropriately the directories and you'll explicitly copy file contents (e.g. using [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) functions or [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), [close(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/close.2.html) system calls....). Notice that [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) (called by [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)...) is required to read or write any content from a file (even using [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)...) Of course, to copy a file, you need to open it, open its fresh copy, read it and write to the copy in a loop, and close both source and destination files. But you should close (both source & destination files) once the copy is done. BTW, a given [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) could have several hundreds (or thousands of) open file descriptors (see [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)...) and [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) also consume one.

<sup>(your number of opened file descriptors (most of them being directories, with  [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html)) is bounded by the file tree depth so is practically likely to be small, less than a hundred; and using clever caching with [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) you could even avoid that)</sup>

BTW, `cp` is part of GNU [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) which is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study its source code.  And you might also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what `cp` is doing.

Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and also [*Operating System : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (both are freely downloadable, as chapters in PDF)

There is no way to copy the content of one file with a single [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). You need a loop. But look also into the Linux specific [copy_file_range(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html) which I don't recommend, better loop on POSIX  [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)

Comment: Thanks! i have edited the question as there were confusions between Linux system calls and C system libraries. I hope the question is unambiguous now.

Comment: Thanks for your response! 
I understand we can walk through a given directory using nftw and perform an operation on each entry individually BUT the problem is- we are still '**opening every file** in the directory for copying the contents' (am i getting it right?). I need a way to skip this.
Say, there are 50 files (with a lot of data in them) in dir1 that need to be replicated in dir2,  We just should be able to copy them w/o bothering about the contents of the files (and opening those). Can that not be achieved?

Comment: You can't avoid open(2) to copy a file.You look confused. I recommend taking days to read the material I linked to. I don't have time or space to explain much more, and you need to takes several days (or weeks) in reading and learning.